# sqlplus is stuck when I drop a procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g

My script is used to drop a database link from another schema. It works good.

```
connect deploy/deploy@qa

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE misc.drop_db_link AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop database link link_name';
END drop_db_link;
/

BEGIN
        misc.drop_db_link;
END;
/

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop procedure misc.drop_db_link';
END;
/
```

But, I want to make it cleaner. So I moved the last statement to the second procedure.  This time, sqlplus shows the first procedure created successfully and no further output. sqlplus is stuck.

```
connect deploy/deploy@qa

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE misc.drop_db_link AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop database link link_name';
END drop_db_link;
/

BEGIN
    misc.drop_db_link;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop procedure misc.drop_db_link';
END;
/
```

Comment: Um... For what purpose are you creating a `PROCEDURE` only to immediately drop it? Why not just call the command?

Comment: Are you sure you actually left one of the slashes in the script? And yes, why use a procedure at all?

Comment: @jpmc26 The purpose is to drop a db link from another schema. deploy and misc are different schema.

Comment: @AlexPoole see my above comment.

Comment: So you can create a procedure in the other schema, but you can't directly drop a DB link in that schema? Does your current script have a / at the end?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, you can't directly drop a DB in another schema. I edited my current script. Did I miss any / ?

Comment: I'm gonna throw out something to try. What if you `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=MISC` and then drop the link? Does that work?

Comment: @jpmc26 I tested your theory, although I don't like it. I got "insufficient privileges" error even I used system user account.